# Resizing bitmap in android

Tags: android, bitmap

I have bit map in size 908 x 1003.
My screen size is 480 x 800.
I want to display this bitmap in full screen. 
I am resizing the bit map but there are still empty spaces
in my screen (The image displayed in full height but not width).

This is my code

I have a bitmap called processedMap(908 x 1003).

```
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);



    int widthPix = (int) Math.ceil(dm.widthPixels * (dm.densityDpi / 160.0));
    int heightPix = (int) Math.ceil(dm.heightPixels * (dm.densityDpi / 160.0));

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(processedMap, (int) widthPix, (int)heightPix, true);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
```

The weird thing is that when I increase the size of the widthPix (like widthPix + 40), the problem is fixed! Please help me.

Comment: By the way, I need to do this using the method above. I know that scaletype.fitxy displays my image in fullscreen. However, I will use this bitmap in zooming where we use scaletype.matrix.

Comment: So basically your widthPix calculation is incorrect.. and does not equal the screen width size. Why arent you simply getting the screen width directly. - why include the dpi bit. If widthPix is equal to your screen width, It is possible that in the scaling it does not stretch the image, so you are left with Gaps along the sides. You should ideally calculate the required height and width, that will cover the screen without stretching.

Answer (score 0):

Your specific problem is here:

```
(dm.densityDpi / 160.0)
```

Put a breakpoint on this statement then evaluate this calculation.  You are dividing 2 ints without a cast and since it's in brackets, it is evaluated before the multiplication. The nett result is that you lose the fractional part, e.g. 240 / 160 => 1

Use this:

```
(dm.densityDpi / 160.0d)
```

Having said that, Doomsknight's comment is sound.  Since you only need to deal with pixels, why complicate it?

Comment: No luck. I even tried to give numbers without any calculation. I still get spaces around the image. Dm.widthpixels gives me the real size of the device right?

Comment: Yes.  Please show the XML layout where you define the ImageView.

Comment: I create the ImageView programatically.                                           Bitmap processedMap = im.draw();
  imageView = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
  imageView.setImageBitmap(processedMap);

Comment: How do you size and layout the imageview?  Using layout params?

Comment: Yes. LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1);

Comment: You've beaten me ;)  One last thing I can think of without stepping through your code, how about setting the scale type of the imageview?